# How security programs like firewall, IPS and IDS have access to network data?

Tags: networking, kernel, security

It is said that kernel responsible for the transport, internet and network access layers for a network data. Then, the network data is passed on the appropriate process based on port number.

How security programs like firewall, IPS and IDS have access to network data that do not belong them while they are just user level program and not part of kernel? How about proxy server?

How come the network data has to pass the firewall first before the appropriate process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, those security programs contain two parts, one running in kernel space, one running in user space. The `user space` part is only an interface to iteract with kernel space part.

For example, iptables contains:

- netfilter, a set of hooks to the networking code in the kernel. It
  also includes mechanisms for passing packets to user space program.
- `ip_tables`, a module that uses netfilter to troubleshoot the
  network packets, set up rules...
- `iptables`, a user space tool for setting up rules in the
  ip_tables module.

Netfilter and `ip_iptables` run in kernel space while `iptables` run in user space.

Comment: I do have experience with iptables and have read about Netfilter on Wikipedia but it is still unclear to me. How the security programs (process) receive the network data that are not supposed for them?

Comment: I think you should read through the `netfiilter` documentation or source and try to understand how it work, or how `netfilter` hook into the kernel.

Comment: It seems like netfilter is for Linux kernel. How about FreeBSD?

Comment: I haven't used `FreeBSD` yet, but google give me: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/firewall.html

Comment: Somehow I missed to mention something in the previous answer. How netfilter is connected to transport layer, internet layer and network access layer in kernel? How is it connected to application layer? netfilter is for Linux kernel. Somehow I have not found relevant documents. How about FreeBSD?

Comment: Because `netfilter` can hook to kernel networking code. You must dig in to `netfilter` source code for more details.

Comment: I assume that Wireshark also uses netfilter when the OS uses Linux kernel.

Comment: Add the promisc mode to your answer and it is perfect.